# Nonlinear Programming understanding a proof

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

This is from Nonlinear Programming Bazaraa. But I don't understand how the lower semicontinuous was used? How it said that there is a $\lambda$ that $f(x) > f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x)>f(x_1) $
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is established as follows:

Since $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $x$, and $f(x) > f(x_1)$ by assumption,  we can find the point $\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x$ in a neighborhood of $x$ such that
$$f[\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x] > f(x_1).\tag1$$

But $f$ is strictly quasiconvex, and $0<\lambda<1$ and $x_1 \ne x$, so
$$
f[\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x] < \max\{f(x_1),f(x)\}.\tag2
$$
Finally $$f(x)>f(x_1)\tag3$$ by assumption. Conclude:
$$
f(x) \stackrel{(3)}= \max\{f(x_1), f(x)\} \stackrel{(2)}> f[\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x]\stackrel{(1)}> f(x_1).
$$